# Проблема с ООП(небольшая)

Tags: python-3.x

Я сделал по ООП модели два юнита, которые сражаются друг с другом до тех пор, пока один не победит(HP одного из них станет равно нулю).

Проблема лишь в том что они наносят одинаковый урон друг другу,  например 5 урона один раз нанёс и дальше такой же урон до конца боя (так у обоих юнитов). Hа параметры урона  я использовал функцию random.randint из модуля random. Как сделать так, чтобы они каждый ход наносили рандомный урон,а не раз за разом одинаковый урон.

```
import random


class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage

    def attack(self, enemy):
        enemy.hp -= self.damage
        print(
            f"Юнит {self.name} атаковал юнита {enemy.name} на {self.damage} урона. У юнита {self.name} осталось {self.hp} HP"
            f"\nУ его противника {enemy.name} осталось {enemy.hp} HP")
        print(" ")


def Battle(warrior_1, warrior_2):
    while warrior_1.hp > 0 and warrior_2.hp > 0:
        Act = random.randint(1, 2)
        if Act == 1:
            warrior_1.attack(warrior_2)
        elif Act == 2:
            warrior_2.attack(warrior_1)
    else:
        if warrior_1.hp < 0:
            print(f"Юнит {warrior_2.name} победил. У Юнита {warrior_2.name} осталось {warrior_2.hp} HP")
        if warrior_2.hp < 0:
            print(f"Юнит {warrior_1.name} победил. У Юнита {warrior_1.name} осталось {warrior_1.hp} HP")


Swordsman = Warrior("Мечник", 100, random.randint(0, 10))
Warrior_with_axe = Warrior("Воин с топором", 100, random.randint(0, 10))

Battle(Swordsman, Warrior_with_axe)
```

Comment: Я вижу слудующее: вы имеете метод `__init__` класса `Warrior`, который принимает 4 аргумета. (4ый - урон). Но передаёте вы только 3 аргумента при создании `Swordsman` и `Warrior_wirh_axe`.

Comment: так как `self.damage` нигде не меняется, то и урон везде одинаковый. Для решения, вместо указания его один раз нужно везде использовать `random.randint` а не только при создании объекта